# How To Combine Prototype Function Styles in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype, duplicates

I am getting dinged for duplication by [CodeClimate](https://codeclimate.com) for 5 "simular" prototype functions as duplications resulting in a D rating.

My knowledge is lacking on how to combine / not repeat similar code them to improve my "code style". Your help will be greatly appreciated.

**The Prototypes:**

```
SomeThing.prototype.destination = function(path) {
  if (!arguments.length) {
    return this.path(this._destination);
  }
  assert(is.string(path), 'You must pass a destination path string.');

SomeThing.prototype.frontmatter = function(frontmatter) {
  if (!arguments.length) {
    return this._frontmatter;
  }
  assert(is.boolean(frontmatter), 'You must pass a boolean.');

SomeThing.prototype.clean = function(clean) {
  if (!arguments.length) {
    return this._clean;
  }
  assert(is.boolean(clean), 'You must pass a boolean.');

SomeThing.prototype.concurrency = function(max) {
  if (!arguments.length) {
    return this._concurrency;
  }
  assert(is.number(max), 'You must pass a number for concurrency.');
```

Comment: What do you mean with "combine"? Do you want to avoid repeating `SomeThing.prototype`? Then use `Object.assign`.

Comment: I think the repetition is the arguments.length check coupled with the similar assertion.

Comment: I do believe both of you are correct - @Travis. I keep looking at this [Mozilla Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) but like I said, my knowledge isn't helping me with this.

Comment: Turns out the duplication issue is related to the `assert(typeof argumentName === "string");`.  I'll have to refactor how I throw the errors for debugging or ommit the lines in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will DRY out your code:

```
function makeProp(prop, type) {
    return function(someArg) {
        if (!arguments.length) return this['_' + prop];
        var msg = 'You must pass a ' + type + ' for ' + prop;
        assert(is[type], msg)
    }
}

Something.prototype = {
    destination: makeProp('destination', 'string'),
    frontmatter: makeProp('frontmatter', 'boolean'),
    clean: makeProp('clean', 'boolean'),
    concurrency: makeProp('concurrency', 'number')
}
```

Comment: if you need to DRY out your code even further, you could swap out the order of the parameters in `makeProp` and then do `var makeBoolean = makeProp.bind(makeProp, 'boolean')` and then `Something.prototype.frontmatter = makeBoolean('frontmatter');`, and the same for 'string' and 'number' if you have additional methods that use those.